# is there a code to use php to check if a remote xml file is accessible before continuing ?

Tags: php, simplexml

i'm fetching a remote xml file `$variable['test'] = 'http://someurl.com/test.xml';` but when the file server is down my whole script stops working!

is there a way to verify if the file is accessible before trying to fetch it ?

Comment: What method are you using to fetch the data? `simplexml_load_file`?

Comment: @kingkero, yes i'm sorry i forgot to explain that

Comment: @kingkero, it was in deed duplicate and thanks again, it worked 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to write a simple check condition. Something like:

```
$var = "http://someurl.com/test.xml";

if($var != NULL){

    //Do the code if you can see the XML.

}

else{

    //The code if your external XML is unreachable.

}
```

You can't see if it's the XML is available without looking. You'll always need to check, and then make sure your code is robust enough to handle the case where it is not.

If you are using something like simplexml_load_file you can easily catch an error like so.

```
$XML = @simplexml_load_file($file);
if ($XML  === false) {
  // Action for the case XML is not present.
}
```

Comment: Why would a string ever be `== NULL`?

Comment: I'm being general. NULL in this case represents the lack of data. If GuestofHonor is using something like SimpleXML then they can just catch the SimpleXML object's no file found error and read it as a boolean.